# Xaml controls from png images

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface

I have two choices to make my ui controls.
I have images of all controls and I can build controls using these image resources or I can create the same look and feel in Xaml without using images.

Which  one is better in terms of performance and why?

Comment: Would you also be able to create the look of all possible visual states (like `MouseOver`, `Pressed`, `Disabled`, `Focused, `Selected`, etc.) with your images? And will the images scale properly when your controls are resized, especially when aspect ratio isn't kept? In short, UI controls from images are not an option.

Answer (score 0):

hello @TRS it is always better if you can avoid usage of images because you will require extra space for those and it eventually make your project heavy.Also your project performance will be tremendously affected if image are more in number because loading of image take time which is directly related to performance.